# Django Error NoReverseMatch at /new_bid/1 Reverse for 'addwatchlist' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am somewhat new to Django. I'm encountering an error that I find very odd.
The site allows a user to place a bid (enter a number amount) on an item, similar to ebay.
When I enter the number, I get the error "NoReverseMatch at /new_bid/1
Reverse for 'addwatchlist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addwatchlist/(?P[0-9]+)$']

This is odd because that area of the code (new_bid in views.py) has nothing to do with the addwatchlist. The addwatchlist in views.py adds this particular item to a list, for that user. It's just so a user can keep track of any items on the site they want to watch.

The watchlist function works completely - I can add an item to my watchlist and it's fine.
I don't know why this function is interacting with my other function, new_bid, which adds a bid for the item. I know this error usually is related to the url or the way the html template calls the url but I really don't know why they two are interacting. Is it because they both use "id": listingid ? Any help is appreciated!

urls.py for relevant urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path("addwatchlist/<int:listingid>", views.addwatchlist, name="addwatchlist"),
    path("new_bid/<int:listingid>", views.new_bid, name="new_bid"),
]
```

views.py for watchlist:

```
def addwatchlist(request, listingid):
    if request.user.username:
        entry = Watchlist()
        entry.user = request.user.username
        entry.listingid = listingid
        entry.save()
        return redirect('listingpage', id=listingid)
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

views.py for adding your bid:

```
def new_bid(request, listingid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auction_to_add = Listings.objects.get(id=listingid)
        total_bid = request.POST.get("total_bid")
        bid = Bid.objects.create(user=request.user, listingid=auction_to_add, bid=total_bid)
        auction_to_add.bids.add(bid)
        auction_to_add.last_bid = bid
        auction_to_add.save()
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "id": listingid,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "id": listingid,
        })
```

Part of html file for placing your bid:

```
 <p class="lead" align="justify"><strong>Place your Bid : </strong></p>
        <form action="{% url 'new_bid' product.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="newbid" placeholder="Your 
      Bid">
            </div>
            <p align="justify"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
```

Part of html file for adding to watchlist:

```
<a href="{% url 'addwatchlist' product.id %}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add to Watchlist</button></a>
```

This is the part of views.py that will display the page itself for the specific item on the site:

```
def listingpage(request, id):
    comments = Comments.objects.filter(listingid=id)
    item = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "id": id,
        "comments": comments,
        "product": item,
    })
```

Comment: are you passing `product` to the template via context?

Comment: @ruddra 'product' is coming from the views.py - to display the page itself. I should have added this before - I have edited my post and you can see this at the very bottom now. So this will just display the page for each item on the site.

Comment: Strangely the error message does not fit to your urls.py, so stupid question: are you sure that the urls.py that you posted is the one used in your project? Please restart the server and try again. What happens if you call new_bid/1 from the browser manually?

Comment: @Razenstein when I call new_bid/1 from the browser I get the same error message as before